# RewrittenCommandText in an expression: Nothing is returned

Tags: reporting-services

I have a textbox with the following expression:

```
=DataSets("MyDataSet").RewrittenCommandText
```

But nothing is returned, not even error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RewrittenCommandText` property value is populated at runtime from data extensions that support the [IDbCommandRewriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDbCommandRewriter.aspx) interface. If a data extension doesn't support this interface, RewrittenCommandText will be `Nothing`. The built-in report model data source supports this interface but I don't think it is supported by many other data extensions.

I just tried a standard SQL Server dataset and `RewrittenCommandText` returned `Nothing` even though the SQL is being built by custom DLLs. However, the [CommandText](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.dataprocessing.idbcommand.commandtext.aspx) returned the generated SQL, not the expression being used to generate the SQL so that might work for you.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your input. CommandText works for me too. But it does not do Parameter Substitution. I want to display the (dynamic) query. RewrittenCommandText seemed perfect. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Mine also had no parameter substitution but at least it had the SQL rather than the DLL function calls that my dataset's expression was set to. You could probably write a custom code function to do the parameter replacement for the CommandText.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Do you know any good book/site for learning to write SSRS custom code ?

Comment: SSRS custom code is just Visual Basic. Plenty of examples on the net.